# Consistent builds / remove personal information from binaries

Tags: go, build, stack-trace

I've now realized that Go saves absolute paths to source code in binaries for the purpose of printing stack-traces and the likes.  I don't want to completely remove this information, however, this also means that every developer building the same program will produce an executable with a different checksum.  Before I try to reimplement the build using `chroot` or something like that: isn't there any way to tell Go not to use absolute paths for this purpose?

Comment: A release binary should be built in a consistent, reproducible environment with no personal information to begin with. Once you're doing that, the text of GOPATH isn't consequential.

Comment: @JimB I need it for developers' builds too. There's no point in creating 99.99% similar artifacts 50+ times just so the developers would see their user name in stack traces.

Comment: Regardless, once you have a method for creating a consistent build, this becomes a moot point. There currently is no way to strip the GOPATH value from the filenames (there's an open issue https://golang.org/issue/3467, but it hasn't been a priority for anyone to take it on).

Comment: @JimB seriously, I'm not asking you how to run my builds... You don't know the reasons and the circumstances, no need to second-guess me. I've asked a very specific question. You know that's not possible: please post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I know it doesn't *directly* address what you asked, but @JimB's suggestion does indicate a class of solutions to the problem you seem to be having.

One of the easier ones (I think) would be to have your developers install [Docker](https://www.docker.com/products/overview) and create an alias so that the `go` command runs:

```
docker run --rm --tty --volume $GOPATH:/go golang:1.7.1(-$YOUR_PLATFORM) go
```

Then, every build (and test and run) thinks it's using a GOPATH of `/go` and your developers' checksums won't disagree based on that.

See [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang/) for more info.

Comment: No, this is neither an answer to a very simple question, nor a real solution. Docker is a can of worms of it's own (at where I work we build a patched version of this... ahem, very nice program, but that's beside the point). This is not a real solution for people who want to build on Windows or Mac (too slow, impossible to debug, total messup with file ownership etc.) This doesn't play well with any build system in existence. And, unfortunately, I know this, because this is what I do today, and I hate doing this.

Answer (score 0):

> isn't there any way to tell Go not to use absolute paths for this purpose?

Nowadays there is:  `-trimpath`.

https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies explains:

> -trimpath

> remove all file system paths from the resulting executable.
> Instead of absolute file system paths, the recorded file names
> will begin either a module path@version (when using modules),
> or a plain import path (when using the standard library, or GOPATH).

Answer (score 0):

To extend what [erik258](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1726083/erik258) response, you also need to fix the GOPATH.

I think if you have modules enabled, it doesn't really mater. I just set mine to /home/runner/go to match what the github runners have and it is working like a charm.

This is the entire build command I use that yields exactly the same binary on my machine and in GitHub actions

```
export CGO_ENABLED=0 
export GOOS=linux 
export GOARCH=amd64
export GOPATH=/home/runner/go

build="go build -trimpath -tags lambda.norpc -buildvcs=false -compiler gc"
$build -o cmd/lambda/package/bootstrap cmd/lambda/main.go
```